# Problem to finish the question: If $n > 4$ is compound then $(n-1)!\equiv 0\pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem to finish the question: If $n > 4$ is compound then $(n-1)!\equiv 0\pmod n$.
If $n = a\cdot b$ there is no problem, once $a, b$ are factors of $(n-1)!$. The problem is when $ n = p^2$. I know that once $p > 4$ then  $p^2 \ge 3$. But, how can I justify that $p^2$ is a factor of $(n-1)!$?

Thanks a lot.
Cordially

Comment: Consider $p$ and $2p$

Comment: Could you be more clear? Sorry.

Comment: Think about where you can find two factors $p$ in $(n-1)!$

Comment: I assume that by "compound" you mean "composite". Is that correct?

Comment: Other hint: Does $p^2$ divide $(2p-1)!$? Does $p^2$ divide $(2p)!$?

Comment: If your MathJax code says (\mod n), then you see $(\mod n)$, but if your code says \pmod n then you see $\pmod n$.  I edited accordingly.  If more than one item follows \pmod then you need {braces}; thus \pmod 53 yields $\pmod 53$, but \pmod{53} yields $\pmod{53}$.  With things like \pmod \lambda no braces are needed since \lambda or \infty or the like behaves in this respect like a single character. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, I intended to write composite. Sorry @PM2Ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n = p^2$, clearly $p$ must be contained in $(n-1)! = (n-1)(n-2)\cdots 1.$

So $p|(n-1)!$ . Note that $2p < n$, why? Suppose $2p > n$, then $p > {n\over 2}$, so that $p^2 > \frac{n^2}{4}$,  but remember you have $n>4$, if $p^2>\frac{n^2}{4}$, then $p^2>n^2$, a contradiction. So $2p < n$. Therefore $2p$ is also contained in $(n-1)!$.

Thus $p^2 = n | (n-1)!$, and $(n-1)! = 0 \pmod n$.

Comment: Really really apologize for the terrible formatting, I know 0 MathJax but am going to learn, feel free to edit to change this formatting.

Comment: Thank you Ludolila, again I'm sorry for the formatting, first time on math.stackexchange, this won't happen in future.

Answer (score 3):

If $n=p^2$, $n-1=p^2-1$, so $\;p, 2p,\dots ,(p-1)p$ are distinct factors of $\;(n-1)!$, hence $p^{p-1}$  is a factor thereof. As $n=p^2>4$, $p\ge 3$, and $p-1\ge 2$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally: define $\upsilon_p(n!)=k\iff \left(p^k\mid n!,\, p^{k+1}\nmid n!\right)$

(this is standard notation; see [this paper](http://www.taharut.org/imo/LTE.pdf)).

$\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the [Floor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), i.e. the largest integer smaller than or equal to $x$.

$$\upsilon_p(n!)=\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n}{p^2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n}{p^3}\rfloor\cdots$$

In this case:

$$\upsilon_p((p^2-1)!)=\lfloor\frac{p^2-1}{p}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{p^2-1}{p^2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{p^2-1}{p^3}\rfloor\cdots$$

$$=\lfloor p-\frac{1}{p}\rfloor+\lfloor 1-\frac{1}{p^2}\rfloor+\cdots=(p-1)+0+\cdots=p-1$$

Since $p^2>4$, we get $p\ge 3$ and $p-1\ge 2$, so $$p^{p-1}\mid (p^2-1)!\implies p^2\mid (p^2-1)!$$